# Highlight continuous values in column

Tags: excel

I have several column all with either `OK`,`[BLANK]`,`Fail` (these results are generated by formulae). Note: any of these 3 results is separated by 4 blank cells.

I want continuous cells with `OK` appearing more than 4 times to be highlighted with special formatting. It want the formatting to continue looking for cells with `OK` if a blank cell appears but to stop if `Fail` appears. After Fail I want it to restart counting again.

For instance, in the array below only the string of `OK` values which appear 5 times continuously (count should not be interrupted by BLANK cell) should be highlighted. Also, please note that in my array all results (`OK`,`[BLANK]`,`Fail`) are spaced by 4 blank columns.

```
Fail
OK
OK
OK
Fail
Fail
OK
OK
OK

OK
OK
OK
Fail
```

Greatly, appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you look for a programm or help within excel to format? Please add more detail!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub check4()
Dim a As Range
Set a = Selection.Cells(1)

For n = 0 To 100
v = a.Offset(n, 0).Value

Select Case v
Case "OK": countOK = countOK + 1
Case "": ign = ign + 1
Case Else
countOK = 0: ign = 0
End Select
Select Case countOK
Case 5
For x = n - (4 + ign) To n
a.Offset(x, 0).Font.Color = ColorConstants.vbRed
Next x
Case Is > 5
a.Offset(n, 0).Font.Color = ColorConstants.vbRed
End Select
Next n
End Sub
```